# Can't get my JComboBox to Populate from the Database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I have been trying for hours to get my JComboBox to populate with the column names in my database, With no success. At first I loaded three column names that are within my table to put into it and then stripped it down to just one to see if it will even work.

And yet I get a NullPointerException

Can someone please give me guidance on how to make this work?

Thanks.

```
    public BlankStock() {
        conman = new ConnectionManager();
        con = conman.CreateConnection();

        initComponents();

        BlankBox.setModel(fillBlankBox());
        BlankBox.removeAllItems();
        BlankBox.addItem("Please Select...");

        fillBlankBox();
    }

    public DefaultComboBoxModel fillBlankBox() {

        try {

            String qry = "SELECT MCOBlanks FROM `blanks` WHERE MCOBlanks = 'blanks' ";
            //Connection con = null;

            // con = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
            System.out.println(rs.getStatement().toString());

            ComboBoxModel cbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();            

            DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object data1 = BlankBox.getSelectedItem();
                cbm.addListDataListener(BlankNo);
            }
            dcbm.addElement(BlankBox);
            BlankBox.setModel(cbm);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
//        } finally {
//            try {con.close();} catch (SQLException e){;}
//        }
        return cbm;
```

Comment: Which line is throwing `NPE`?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? (mark it in your code with a comment as we cannot see your linenumbers)

Comment: I suggest you consider some ideas about what could be bad practices in your code: always close ResultSet, Statement (and Connection if necessary) in a finally  {} block.  Never leave an empty exception block as the one you have commented there.  I strongly recommend you never open Connections to a database from a desktop client (unless this is an academic exercise), but use a connection pool on an application server instead, and have your desktop app communicate with it.  Separe presentation code from data retrieving too, since your code will be cleaner and more reusable.

Comment: and do not create an Swing JComponent inside try - catch - finally block, use local variables intialized before ..., set model to JComboBox after finally block is executed ResultSet

Comment: The NPE is being thrown in a completely different class which is to do with the JComboBox.java file And then returns to the line where it says BlankBox.setModel(fillBlankBox());